# 301 redirects with regular expressions

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm having some trouble using the right code for my .htaccess file.
What I'm trying to accomplish is this:

We have a QR code generator which generates random url'Ss like this:

http://mydomain.com?APP-V2/7091c104-32a8-4680-9c07-a75c3ee61d7a/00

I need to redirect all these url's to the homepage, http://mydomain.com.
How to I write the wildcard in my htaccess file? Basically everything after mydomain.com?APP-V2/ should be redirected.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically everything after mydomain.com?APP-V2/ should be redirected.

If you want:

```
http://mydomain.com/?APP-V2/7091c104-32a8-4680-9c07-a75c3ee61d7a/00
```

to be redirected to:

```
http://mydomain.com/
```

Then you just get rid of the query string (e.g. `?APP-V2/7091c104-32a8-4680-9c07-a75c3ee61d7a/00`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^APP-V2/
RewriteRule ^$ /? [L]
```

But if you want everything after the `?APP-V2/`, you need this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^APP-V2/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ /%1? [L]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Note that there is no slash after the .com. So rather than .com/?APP-V2/ it is .com?APP-V2/

Comment: @RLemon it doesn't matter, if you click on that link, the request sent to `mydomain.com` is `GET /?APP-V2/7091c104-32a8-4680-9c07-a75c3ee61d7a/00 HTTP/1.1` etc.

Comment: You are correct. Provided code is working. Due to a specific set-up it wasn't working for me in the beginning. Now it does. Thanks!